# If $u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{u_{n} + a_{n} + 1} $ for $(a_n)$ positive and bounded, then $(u_n)$ converges iff $(a_n)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ denote a positive, bounded, real sequence, and  $(u_n)$ the sequence defined by $u_0 > 0$ and, for every $n\ge0$, 
$$u_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{u_{n} + a_{n} + 1}$$
How to show that the sequence  $(u_{n})$ converges if, and only if , the sequence $(a_{n})$ converges?

Answer (score 2):

Since $u_0>0$, it is clear from the recurrence that $u_{n}>0, \forall n\geq 0$. Hence $$\frac{1}{2+M}\leq u_{n}\leq1$$ where $M>0$ is such that  $a_n\leq M$. So if $u_n\to l\Rightarrow l>0$ and hence $$a_n=\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}-u_n-1\to \frac{1}{l}-l-1$$ Now suppose $a_n\to l.$ Set $b_n=\frac{1}{u_n+a_n+1}-\frac{1}{u_n+l+1}$ and note  that $b_n\to 0$. We've $$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{u_n+l+1}+b_n$$ so that $$u_{n+k+1}-u_{n+1}=\frac{-u_{n+k}+u_{n}}{\left(u_{n+k}+l+1\right)\left(u_n+l+1\right)}+b_{n+k}-b_n$$ Hence $$\left|u_{n+k+1}-u_{n+1}\right|\leq c\left|u_{n+k}-u_n\right|+\left|b_{n+k}-b_n\right|$$ where $0\leq c<1$. Setting $A_{(n,k)}=|u_{n+k}-u_n|$ and $B_{(n,k)}= |b_{n+k}-b_n| $ , the relation becomes $$A_{(n+1,k)}\leq c\,A_{(n,k)}+B_{(n,k)}$$ from which one gets $$ A_{(n+1,k)}\leq c^{n+1}A_{(0,k)}+\sum_{r=0}^{n}c^{n-r}B_{(r,k)}  $$ 
Now since $b_n\to 0$, there exist $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B_{(r,k)}\leq \epsilon, \forall r\geq n_0,k\in\mathbb{N}$, for a fixed $\epsilon>0$. So 
$$A_{(n+1,k)}\leq c^{n+1}A_{(0,k)}+\sum_{r=0}^{n_0}c^{n-r}B_{(r,k)}+\epsilon\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n_0}c^r \right)\leq c^{n+1}A_{(0,k)}+C\left(\sum_{r=n-n_0}^{n}c^r \right)+\epsilon\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n_0}c^r \right) $$ where $B_{(r,k)}\leq C, \forall r\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{N}$. Now for large enough $m$, it is clear from the above equation that there is $M'\geq0$ such that $$A_{(n+1,k)}\leq M'\epsilon$$ $\forall n\geq m, k\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this means that the sequence $u_{n}$ is cauchy and hence convergent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you detailed answer.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand how we have $$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{u_n+l+1}+b_n$$ so that $$u_{n+k+1}-u_{n+1}=\frac{u_{n+k}-u_{n}}{\left(u_{n+k}+l+1\right)\left(u_n+l+1\right)}+b_{n+k}-b_n\leq c\left(-u_{n+k}+u_n\right)+(b_{n+k}-b_n)$$. I get $$u_{n+k+1}-u_{n+1}=\frac{-
u_{n+k}+u_{n}}{\left(u_{n+k}+l+1\right)\left(u_n+l+1\right)}+b_{n+k}-b_n $$

Comment: Silly me!  Fortunately that does not matter much. Edited.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks a lot.